# Entity Framework - code first - Too many navigation properties

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, composite-key

I have two tables created with Entity Framework code first that I would like some help with..!

**Tables**

1. AccountLinks, 3 composite keys
2. Guest, 3 composite foreign keys (?)

**Table overview**

[image]

**SQL overview**

[image]

As you can see I have ALOT of navigation properties in my database which I dont want.

**Code for AccountLink**

```
public class AccountLink
    {
        public AccountLink()
        {
            AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
            AccountLinkPermissionAccountOwnerID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
            AccountLinkPermissionGuestID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
        }

        public AccountLink(int accountOwnerID, int guestID, DateTime dateCreated, DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateExpires)
        {
            AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
            AccountLinkPermissionAccountOwnerID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
            AccountLinkPermissionGuestID = new HashSet<AccountLinkPermission>();
            this.AccountOwnerID = accountOwnerID;
            this.GuestID = guestID;
            this.DateCreated = dateCreated;
            this.DateStart = dateStart;
            this.DateExpires = dateExpires;
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int AccountOwnerID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int GuestID { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateExpires { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AccountOwnerID")]
        public virtual AccountOwner AccountOwner { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
        public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionAccountOwnerID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissionGuestID { get; set; }
    }
```

**Code for AccountLinkPermissions**

```
public class AccountLinkPermission
    {
        public AccountLinkPermission()
        {

        }

        public AccountLinkPermission(int accountLinkID, int accountOwnerID, int guestID, int permissionID)
        {
            this.AccountLinkID = accountLinkID;
            this.AccountOwnerID = accountOwnerID;
            this.GuestID = guestID;
            this.PermissionID = permissionID;
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int AccountOwnerID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int GuestID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
        public int PermissionID { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionAccountLinkID")]
        public virtual AccountLink AccountLink { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionAccountOwnerID")]
        public virtual AccountLink AccountLinkAccountOwner { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AccountLinkPermissionGuestID")]
        public virtual AccountLink AccountLinkGuest { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PermissionID")]
        public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    }
```

The reason to why I want 3 composite keys is because I want to prevent duplicates.

**Why I use InverseProperty instead of ForeignKey**

Because I'm using multiple foreign keys linked to the same table, EF is not able to determine by convention which navigation properties belong together. Instead of using the property [ForeignKey] I have to use [InverseProperty] which defines the navigation property on the other end of the relationship.

**Code for User**

```
public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
            AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();
        }

        public User(string firstName, string lastName, string email,
            string password, string passwordSalt, int agreeUserAgreement)
        {
            UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
            AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();

            this.FirstName = firstName ?? string.Empty;
            this.LastName = lastName ?? string.Empty;
            this.Email = email;
            this.DateRegistered = Helpers.TimeZoneExtension.GetCurrentDate();
            this.DateLastActive = Helpers.TimeZoneExtension.GetCurrentDate();
            this.Password = password;
            this.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
            this.IsDeleted = 0;
            this.AgreeUserAgreement = agreeUserAgreement;
        }

        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateLastActive { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        public string DefaultIpAddress { get; set; }

        public int IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public int AgreeUserAgreement { get; set; }

        public string UserRolesToString { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
    }
```

**Code for AccountOwner**

```
public class AccountOwner : User
{
    public AccountOwner()
    {
        UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
        AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();
    }

    public AccountOwner(string firstName, string lastName, string email,
        string password, string passwordSalt, int agreeUserAgreement)
    {
        UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
        AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();

        this.FirstName = firstName ?? string.Empty;
        this.LastName = lastName ?? string.Empty;
        this.Email = email;
        this.DateRegistered = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
        this.DateLastActive = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
        this.Password = password;
        this.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
        this.IsDeleted = 0;
        this.AgreeUserAgreement = agreeUserAgreement;
    }

    public virtual AccountUsagePremium AccountUsagePremium { get; set; }

    public virtual UploadDirectlyUsagePremium UploadDirectlyUsagePremium { get; set; }

    public override ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public override ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
}
```

**Code for Guest**

```
public Guest()
{
    UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();
}

public Guest(string firstName, string lastName, string email,
    string password, string passwordSalt, int agreeUserAgreement)
{
    UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    AccountLinks = new HashSet<AccountLink>();

    this.FirstName = firstName ?? string.Empty;
    this.LastName = lastName ?? string.Empty;
    this.Email = email;
    this.DateRegistered = TimeZoneExtension.GetCurrentDate();
    this.DateLastActive = TimeZoneExtension.GetCurrentDate();
    this.Password = password;
    this.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
    this.IsDeleted = 0;
    this.AgreeUserAgreement = agreeUserAgreement;
}

public override ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
public override ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
```

**What I need help with**

How do I remove all the navigation properties in my database using code first? I know I messed it up somewhere but that's all I know :)

1 Navigation property in AccountLinks, (User_UserID)

9 Navigtion properties in AccountLinkPermissions

**Bonus question**

In AccountLink table I have three composite keys,
AccountLinkID, AccountOwnerID and GuestID. Is it possible to put auto increment, (identity seed), on AccountLinkID? How would I do that in EF code first?

Comment: I like the drawing :)

Comment: Maybe its better if i become a painter and not a coder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from Guest and AccountOwner classes:

```
public override ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
public override ICollection<AccountLink> AccountLinks { get; set; }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(t => t.AccountLinks); 
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(t => t.UserRoles); 
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountOwner>().ToTable("AccountOwners"); 
modelBuilder.Entity<Guest>().ToTable("Guests");
```

Entities:

```
public class AccountLink
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]    
    public int AccountOwnerID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GuestID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateExpires { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountOwnerID")]
    public virtual AccountOwner AccountOwner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuestID")]
    public virtual Guest Guest { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountLinkPermission> AccountLinkPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class AccountLinkPermission 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("AccountLink"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AccountLinkID { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("AccountLink"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AccountOwnerID { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("AccountLink"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int GuestID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int PermissionID { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountLink AccountLink { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81766/discussion-between-alex-polyankin-and-reft).

Comment: Have submitted a new question about another similiar problem(i know..).. If you want to snag some easy points theres a link to it in the chat